# org.springframework.beans.factory.nosuchbeandefinitionexception no bean named. in Liferay

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, liferay

i have deleted all the files(10) in META-INF. after that i run the service builder it showing `org.springframework.beans.factory.nosuchbeandefinitionexception` no bean named. and it did not generate the all files(10) under META-INF,even though i restart the server. even also clean the temp in bundles and even i deleted the project.

```
Buildfile: F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\build.xml
    build-service:
         [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\classes
         [java] Loading jar:file:/F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
         [java] Loading jar:file:/F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
         [java] Loading file:/F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
         [java] Loading jar:file:/F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
         [java] 13:48:22,125 INFO  [PortalImpl:278] Global lib directory /F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/lib/ext/
         [java] 13:48:22,125 INFO  [PortalImpl:298] Portal lib directory /F:/sudheer-workspace/eclipse/workspace/bundles/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
         [java] Building Library
         [java] Building FileUploader
         [java] Error on line 73, column 33 in com/liferay/portal/tools/servicebuilder/dependencies/model_impl.ftl
         [java] serviceBuilder.getSqlType(packagePath + ".model." + entity.getName(), column.getName(), column.getType()) is undefined.
         [java] It cannot be assigned to sqlType
         [java] The problematic instruction:
         [java] ----------
         [java] ==> assignment: sqlType=serviceBuilder.getSqlType(packagePath + ".model." + entity.getName(), column.getName(), column.getType()) [on line 73, column 33 in com/liferay/portal/tools/servicebuilder/dependencies/model_impl.ftl]
         [java] ----------
         [java] Java backtrace for programmers:
         [java] ----------
         [java] freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 73, column 33 in com/liferay/portal/tools/servicebuilder/dependencies/model_impl.ftl
         [java] serviceBuilder.getSqlType(packagePath + ".model." + entity.getName(), column.getName(), column.getType()) is undefined.
         [java] It cannot be assigned to sqlType
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:111)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:179)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:417)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:299)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.CompressedBlock.accept(CompressedBlock.java:73)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
         [java]     at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
         [java]     at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.freemarker.FreeMarkerUtil.process(FreeMarkerUtil.java:49)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.freemarker.FreeMarkerUtil.process(FreeMarkerUtil.java:39)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._processTemplate(ServiceBuilder.java:4446)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._createModelImpl(ServiceBuilder.java:2420)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:1023)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
         [java]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:176)
        [mkdir] Created dir: F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
       [delete] Deleting: F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\LibraryPortlet-portlet-service.jar
    compile-java:
        [javac] Compiling 27 source files to F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
        [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
        [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
          [zip] Building zip: F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\LibraryPortlet-portlet-service.jar
       [delete] Deleting directory F:\sudheer-workspace\eclipse\workspace\plugins\portlets\LibraryPortlet-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 7 seconds
```

Comment: paste your `service.xml` and please also mention the version of liferay you are using. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From error it seems your LibraryPortlet-portlet is not able to compile properly kindly check below 2 things.

1. Your Service.xml is written properly
2. Check javac version which your eclipse is using to build while running ant build-service as class files seems to have version conflict. Try javac runtime 1.6
   Hope it helps !!!